# Show that partial derivatives exist at every point and that they are continuous

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have a problem with the following question:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x,y) = |x+y|\sin|x+y|$

a) Show that the function $f(x,y)$ has derivatives at every point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
b) Find the points where the partial derivatives are continuous.
c) Find the points where the function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable.

EDIT:
What I have managed to do so far:

When $x + y > 0$

$f(x,y) = (x + y)sin(x+y)$

$ \displaystyle{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} =\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h} =$

$ \displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{(x+y+h)sin(x+y+h)-(x+y)sin(x+y)}{h} =$




$ \displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{(x+y+h)sin(x+y+h) - (x+y+h)sin(x+y) }{h}+ \displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{ (x+y+h)sin(x+y) -(x+y)sin(x+y)}{h}=$




$ \displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{(x+y+h)(sin(x+y+h) - sin(x+y)) }{h}$ 

$+ \displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{sin(x+y)((x+y+h) - (x+y))}{h}=$




$ \displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}(x+y+h).\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{(sin(x+y+h) - sin(x+y)) }{h}$ 

$+ sin(x+y).\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{((x+y+h) - (x+y))}{h}=$




$ (x+y).\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{(sin(x+y+h) - sin(x+y)) }{h}$
$+ sin(x+y).\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{((x+y+h) - (x+y))}{h}=$




$ (x+y).\displaystyle{cos(x+y)}$
$+ sin(x+y).\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{h}{h}=$




Finally, we get:

$\displaystyle{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} = (x+y).\displaystyle{cos(x+y)}+ sin(x+y)$




Let's find the other derivative:

$ \displaystyle{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}} =\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h} = \displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{(x+y+h)sin(x+y+h)-(x+y)sin(x+y)}{h}$

So we get the same result as for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$
$\displaystyle{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}} = (x+y).\displaystyle{cos(x+y)}+ sin(x+y)$




When $x + y < 0$

$f(x,y) = -(x + y)sin(-(x+y)) \Rightarrow f(x,y) = -(x + y)(-sin(x+y)) \Rightarrow $
$ f(x,y) = (x + y)sin(x+y)$

Consequently the partial derivatives are going to be the same in this case.




When $x + y = 0$

$f(x,y) = 0.sin(0) \Rightarrow f(x,y) = 0$

$ \displaystyle{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} =\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h} =\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{(0+h)-h}{h} =0$

$\displaystyle{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}} = 0$

Is this enough to show that there are partial derivatives at every point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$?
The partial derivatives seem to be continues everywhere but how do I put this in terms of mathematics?

Comment: Ok. Any attempts or thoughts?

Comment: I have to remove the absolute value in order to differentiate. I approach the problem when x+y < 0 and when x + y >= 0 and it turns out that the function is the same in both cases because sin(-a) = -sin(a). So the derivatives can be easily found and they exist everywhere. It seems to be quite the obvious approach but I have no idea how to describe in the language of mathematics.

Comment: When the question wants you to show the existence of derivatives, you have to work by the definition. Also, since you had a thought process, why not include all that in your original post?

Comment: I will, sure, give me a few minutes.

Comment: The method of "removing the absolute value in order to differentiate" only works for points away from the line $y=-x$. You must handle the case $y=-x$ separately.

Comment: I have given my reasoning. What do you think?

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to use known results such as the chain-rule and derivatives of sine. polynomials, and the absolute value (where the derivative exists) to handle the question for most points in the plane. However, you do need to consider the definition of the *partial* derivative, because you've violated it in your final calculation. You don't need to go back the limits of difference quotients, but you do need to understand what partial differentiation is. You cannot hold $y$ constant while differentiating with respect to $x$, and satisfy $x + y = 0$ at the same time.

Comment: @Rebellos What do you think?

Comment: Ok, so when x+y>0 and x+y<0 everything is fine, right? Can you explain a bit more about the last case when x+y=0? @PaulSinclair

Comment: Yes, everything is fine for $x + y \ne 0$, though unnecessarily complicated. But partial differentiation with respect to $x$ examines how the function changes when $x$ changes while $y$ is held constant. But you cannot change $x$ while $y$ is held constant and still satisfy $x + y = 0$.

Comment: Then the derivatives should not exist when $x+y=0$? @PaulSinclair

Comment: They can exist. But you did not calculate them correctly. You have to look at it as a function of $x$ for constant $y$. You cannot have $x + y = 0$ always for such a function.

Comment: I really don't see the point of (c) if the claim in (a) is true.

Comment: (a) should say "partial derivatives". I do not know if the omission is yours or in your source. (c) is talking about the total derivative, which can fail to exist even if both partials exist. The partial derivatives test only the behavior of the function in two specific directions. The total derivative tests its behavior in every direction.

Answer (score 1):

You have that $$\mathrm df=|x+y|\mathrm d\sin|x+y|+\sin|x+y|\mathrm d|x+y|=|x+y|\cos|x+y|\mathrm d|x+y|+\sin|x+y|\mathrm d|x+y|=(|x+y|\cos|x+y|+\sin|x+y|)\mathrm d|x+y|=(|x+y|\cos|x+y|+\sin|x+y|)\frac{x+y}{|x+y|}\mathrm d(x+y)=\left((x+y)\cos|x+y|+\frac{x+y}{|x+y|}\sin|x+y|\right)(\mathrm dx+\mathrm dy),$$ for every point not on the line $x=-y.$

Comment: How can you differentiate when you have absolute value? @Allawonder

Comment: @SinestroWhite Yes, except from the points where the argument of the absolute value function vanishes; hence the last clause in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(x,y) = h(g(x,y))$ where $h(t) = |t|\sin |t|$ and $g(x,y) = x + y$. When taking the partial derivatives, use the chain rule on this composition.

Comment: What do you find wrong about this $ \displaystyle{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} =\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h} =\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{(0+h)-h}{h} =0$ when $x+y=0$

Comment: That it is not true that $f(x + h, y) - f(x,y) = 0 + h - h$ for every $h$ near $0$. In fact for $h \ne 0$, it isn't true for any $|h| < \pi/2$ (or most $h$ greater than $\pi/2$, but there are exceptions on that side).